# using ppserver with parallel python

Tags: parallel-python, modelica

i'm using parallel python for stearing Monte Carlo simulations in Modelica. Everything works perfectly if i'm working on a single computer with 8 ncpus, however, i fail in adding ppservers to the required job_server.

I start ppserver.py on the computer i want to add but and use the ip-adress on my work computer, but the computer fails to use the server and only uses the cpus on my own computer. As ppserver.py gives little to no information, can someone give me some tips to get this into action ?

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pp is only able to transfer python-code to remote ppserver() and not internal *.exe files or others wihich are executed in the code ...